# Django sending ID with request method get. Good practice?

Tags: django, post, get, request

Short question. My application has an edit page. Users can go through the entries of the database  by

```
<li><a href=edit?id={{ obj.id|add:"-1"}}><b>< </b>previous entry |</a></li>
```

What are the downsides to sending ID's via GET? If POST is a better way to go, can somebody briefly explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not GET vs POST. GET is perfectly appropriate for displaying the edit page of an existing entry: POST should be used to *update* that entry, ie on form submission.

However you should not rely on object primary keys being contiguous. They might be, but for example if ever any are deleted there will be a gap. You should probably query for the next and previous entries explicitly in your view and pass the IDs to your template.

Comment: You're right that I shouldn't rely on the primary keys being contiguous. In this case they are and users are not able to delete entries so I don't have to worry about gaps. For the actual update I do use the POST method.